# Multi page jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Using JasperReports 3.7.6 (with iReport) for generating a report that spans on two pages: report has a table of 18 columns of data, columns from 1 to 10 on the first page and from 11 to 18 on the second, one record of data is displayed on two pages, and lots of data may be gathered. I tried to search of forums, asked question on jasper forum and got no answer.

What will solve this problem?

Comment: Solved! The way to do the trick: 1) make all pages of report as different templates. 2) compose then in one template (elements will overlap) 3) make custom datasource for this report

Comment: Please answer the question with more details, this might become helpful to others.

Comment: Getting the answer to your own question is great - but please actually put it into an answer, then accept it so that your unanswered question does not keep showing up on the list of questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) this is clear I think, but..just make each page of multi page report separated.

2) compose all separated pages in one using copy/pasting XML from one report to another, in the end the only one report will exist and it will contain all elements (which was separated before)

3) write datasource, may be this will suite you:

```java
private final List data; private final Iterator iterator;

private List<IRecord> buffer;
private Iterator<IRecord> bufferIterator;

private IRecord currentValue;

private int pageCount;
private int pageRowNum;

private boolean useBuffer;
private int position;
private int counter;

public MultiPageReportDataSource(List<? extends IRecord> data, int pageRowNum, int pageCount) {
    this.data = data;
    this.iterator = this.data.iterator();
    this.buffer = new LinkedList<IRecord>();
    this.bufferIterator = this.buffer.iterator();
    this.pageRowNum = pageRowNum;
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
    this.counter = pageCount;
}

@Override
public boolean next() throws JRException {
    if (position > 0 && position % pageRowNum == 0) {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0) {
            buffer.clear();
            useBuffer = false;
            counter = pageCount;
        } else {
            useBuffer = true;
            bufferIterator = buffer.iterator();
        }
        position = 0;
    }
    if (useBuffer) {
        if (bufferIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentValue = bufferIterator.next();
        }
    } else {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            currentValue = iterator.next();
            buffer.add(currentValue);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    position++;
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
    Field field = ReflectUtil.field(CashierReportEntity.class, jrField.getName());
    try {
        return ReflectUtil.accessible(field).get(currentValue);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new JRException(e);
    }
}
```